# JavaScript to scroll long page to anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a page with documentation where I need to use anchors. HTML anchors don't work, Javascript doesn't work. I spent some time validating the markup at w3 now, no errors last time I checked.

I have tried `scrollToVisible`, it threw undefined, so I proceeded to reading `var topPos = document.getElementById('anchor1').offsetTop;` and using that, no error but it won't do the scroll. I also tried to use `window` and some random scroll, and `window.scrollTo( 0, 700 );` from mozilla docs, but it won't do the scroll. I then went through the HTML and made sure there are no `height:100%` CSS rules (there are none).

What is can be the reason it won't do the scroll?

a test page content

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
... about 5 x 300 of lipsum ...

<div id="anchor1">
    Anchored. Lorem ipkjcdoeujrb...
</div>

<script>
    var topPos = document.getElementById('anchor1').offsetTop;
    // window.scrollTo(0, topPos);
    window.scrollTo(0, 800);
</script>
```

Please leave a comment if you'd like to see something specific.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution.

```js
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $("html, body").animate({
       scrollTop: $(target).offset().top
        }, 400)
});
```

```css
#top,#middle,#bottom{
  width: 100%;
}
#top{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
}
#middle{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #f00;
}
#bottom{
  height: 1000px;
  background: #0f0;
}
.nav{
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#top">Top</a></li>
    <li><a href="#middle">Middle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#bottom">Bottom</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="top"></div>
<div id="middle"></div>
<div id="bottom"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just do this?

```
window.open('#anchor1', '_self')
```

Comment: Nice way to crash a browser.